Trying to understand std::marker::Sized trait
the Rust documentation says, that this trait should be implemented for "Types with a constant size known at compile time.".
My question is now:
As far as I understood it, that "Size" refers to the struct itself and not to the whole object tree, so that the compiler knows how much space he has to reserve in the stackframe.
But it seems I was wrong, since "the root struct" std::string::String has a fixed size (the struct contains a vec which contains a pointer to the heap, where the dynamically growing happens) and you can declare a local variable of it (in contrast to a dyn trait eg: std::clone::Clone) which needs room on the stack, but it is  not implementing the std::marker::Sized trait.
Why does String not implement the Sized trait and where are the contradictions/issues in my mental model?

Why do you think String isn't Sized? Maybe you're confusing it with str?

Because it is not mentioned here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html
Also I couldn't find the implementation in the Source code ( https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/string.rs.html )

Sized is automatically implemented by the compiler, and does not appear amongst the trait implementations listed in Rustdoc (note it is also absent for u32 and () etc).

I have opened https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/126421, as I think Sized's omission from the documentation is a (long-standing) bug.

Sized isn't listed in the automatic traits, but if a struct does not implement then !Sized is listed (i.e. the display is inverted for Sized) see for example !Sized for str

I’m voting to close this question because it was based on clearly wrong assumptions. I don't see the value in having it answered.
